# Solr stopwords are not working

Tags: lucene, solr4, stop-words

I have solr 4.0 up running on my server. Everything is working fine but the stop words.

Here is my text field

```
 <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Here is my text_general fildtype

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

<filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My stopwords are in the same folder with this schema.xml and here is the part of the list:

```
#Standard english stop words taken from Lucene's StopAnalyzer
#a - contained in English alphabet below
an
and
are
as
at
be
but
by
for
if
in
into
is
it
no
not
of
on
or
```

Any words from this list returns results in solr.

Here is the part of debug:

```
<lst name="responseHeader">


<int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">211</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="debugQuery">true</str>
    <str name="fl">id</str>
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="q">text:an</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="476462" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">5203921</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">826470</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">40853</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">100821</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">735712</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">1826069</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">520764</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">1189586</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">5203322</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">1227851</str></doc>
</result>
<lst name="debug">
  <str name="rawquerystring">text:an</str>
  <str name="querystring">text:an</str>
  <str name="parsedquery">text:an</str>
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">text:an</str>
  <lst name="explain">
    <str name="5203921">
2.2455122 = (MATCH) weight(text:an in 5529393) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  2.2455122 = fieldWeight in 5529393, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    3.5928197 = idf(docFreq=476462, maxDocs=6369076)
    0.625 = fieldNorm(doc=5529393)
</str>
    <str name="826470">
1.9053802 = (MATCH) weight(text:an in 2661240) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  1.9053802 = fieldWeight in 2661240, product of:
    1.4142135 = tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:
      2.0 = termFreq=2.0
    3.5928197 = idf(docFreq=476462, maxDocs=6369076)
    0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=2661240)
</str>
```

It's still getting result from the solr. What am I missing?

Comment: you are sure is not a path problem?

Comment: Which path are you talking about?
I can see the instanceDir from the config admin panel on admin GUI, the path is not wrong at all. My schema and stopwrods files are in the conf folder inside of the instanceDir.

Comment: man     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

Comment: stopwords.txt is in the same folder with the schema.xml.

Comment: this does not mean nothing is in the same folder! use the absolute path and see. /...../..../stopword.txt

Comment: Ok, I can try that. But you know, the **synonyms.txt** is working just fine.  `<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>` I mean this one.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this one? We're seeing the same issue. Solr returns results, but they're not based on the searched term - so, in a way, the stopwords.txt does work since it avoids searching on those.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths. Replace

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
```

by

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="/the/absolute/path/stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
```